# ValleyView Gen7 display does not work on Ubuntu 12.04.5

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, display, intel-graphics

Installed 12.04.5 from the `ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso` image.

After installation, I was able to boot into the graphical user interface desktop every time.

Did `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`.

I cannot see the graphical user interface desktop after reboot. I was redirected to a terminal console every time after boot.

Hardware details from `lshw -c video` tool.

```
*-display
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: ValleyView Gen7
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    version: 0e
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
    resources: irq:111 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:e080(size=8)
```

What further steps or logs could I use to further investigate this issue?

Comment: That was a wrong command for 12.04.5. Why did you run it? The package was already installed and called `xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-trusty`. You just broke the system for no reason.

Comment: Sorry that I did not realise that it will break the system. I did it because I assume that the command could get the correct updated Intel drivers for XOrg environment.

Comment: What is the difference between `xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-trusty` and `xserver-xorg-video-intel`?

Comment: These packages are from different graphical stacks. In 12.04.5 the `lts-trusty` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran a wrong command for no reason.

You can try to fix it by running

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty
```

For more details see [HWE Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: I used the following command on Ubuntu 12.04.5 system.  
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-precise`  
It manage to get into the user interface desktop after reboot.

Comment: Are following commands can be used interchangeably on Ubuntu 12.04.5 system? `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-precise` and `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty`

Comment: There is no `xserver-xorg-lts-precise ` in 12.04.

Comment: Wrong to use `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-precise`? I used it and it seems to work.

Comment: Sry, I was wrong. They added this package too.

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade to an older stack? `-lts-trusty` is better. It was originally installed in 12.04.5.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and pointing out that `-lts-trusty` was originally installed in 12.04.5. I was confused over using `-lts-trusty` over a `precise` distribution.